# JQuery validation with Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, validation

I have a problem with getting the error messages from:

```
format.json { render json: @contactmail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

to my real-time JQuery validation of some text-fields.

When the JQuery method datatype is set to text it prints out all the html of the page I want to validate after render new page. If datatype is JSON Firebug gives me an error 422 and prints something that resembles objects with my error messages.

Any clue to how to do this the correct way?